# How do I prevent 'Uncaught Error' when using Rails UJS for my create method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my controller:

```
def create
  @line_item = @package.line_items.build(line_item_params)
  if @line_item.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to edit_package_path(@package) }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

In app/views/line_items/create.js.coffee:

```
$('table.package-table tbody').append('<%= j render @line_item %>')
```

The log shows that the `line_item` is created, that the controller is handling it as a JS request, and that the `line_item/create.js.coffee` template is being rendered.

The proper HTML is being appended to the tbody as it should be.

But...

The browser shows an error in the console that looks like (in part):

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: (function() {
  $('table.package-table tbody').append('<tr class=\"line-item-line\" id=\"line_item_133\">
```

It goes on to list the entire JS that's being sent by the create.js.coffee template.

This occurs even if I take out all of the code in the template and replace it with a simple `console.log 'boom'` call.

Why am I getting this error in the console? And more importantly, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Probably an obvious question but I can't see an answer to it - is the JS code sent actually valid or not?

Comment: @vlaz Yes. It looks good, and works by appending the appropriate HTML.